# render partial view inside an iframe within asp.net mvc application

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a asp.net mvc application in which I have a partial view named `_GeoApi.cshtml`.

I need to render it inside an **iframe**.

```
<iframe src='@{Html.RenderPartial("_GeoApi");}' id='fram' ></iframe>
```

I get a generated html code :

```
<iframe<script src="/Scripts/External js/jquery-1.8.2.js">
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBCVSBoBAUjAfb-Pfx_qq0ZKUHCitbzsl4&amp;libraries=places&amp;callback=initAutocomplete" async="" defer=""></script>

//content removed for brivety

 src='' id='fram' /&gt; 

                                </iframe<script>
```

So I need to know

1. What are the reasons of this error?
2. How can I fix my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error is caused because you have a `<script>` tag in your `<iframe>` tag.

The solution is to simply provide a URL as the src to a URL where you would render the partial instead of trying to put the contents in the iframe tag.

```
<iframe src='/api/geoApi' id='fram' ></iframe>
```

Then create an ApiController that has a GeoApi action method which renders the "_GeoApi" partial view.